# Detect browser history back

Tags: javascript

There are a lot of posts on this issue, some that lead to a solution, but non of them seems to work for me.

I want to know when a user has pressed the back button on the browser, so that I can take the approprate action. But nothing happens when I press the buttons. I have been trying a few days now, hope someone can shed a light.
Here is my js code

```
function browserButtonEvent() {
    if(window.event) {
        if(window.event.clientX < 40 && window.event.clientY < 0) { //ie

        } 
        else 
        {
            alert("navigation button clicked");
        }
    }
    else {

        if(event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type == 1) {
            alert("Refreshed");         
        }
        if(event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type == 2) {
            alert("Back button pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my test html page. (I have 2 more pages that I use, but one should be enough I think)

```
<body onbeforeunload="browserButtonEvent()">
    <h3>Index</h3>
    <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 600px; height: 600px; background-color: lightblue; margin-top: 200px;">
        <form action="">
            <input type="button" value="Press" onclick="goHistory()"/>
            <br />
            <!--<input type="button" value="Test" id="test" />-->
            <br />
            <a href="page2.html">Page 2 </a>
            <br />
            <a href="page3.html">Page 3 </a>
            <p>Page 1</p>

            <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 150px;">
                <a id="back" style="float: left;">Back</a> 
                <a id="forward" style="float: right;">Forward</a>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you are asking the wrong question. you want to ask "detect browser history back". this can also be triggered by keyboard and mouse shortcuts you know..

Comment: Is it possible that you do enter `browserButtonEvent` but that none of the alerts get called?

Comment: No I do not enter the if clauses. It just checks the if condition, but never enters the body. It's as if the conditions are always false, even if the back button is pressed

Comment: well, what ever you are trying to do is probably against the unspoken law of the internet, that a programer shan't mess around with the browser's back behavior. I would suggest making your money in other, less intrusive, frontiers of internet developed. It would save you a lot a headache...(and the user's also)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `onbeforeonunload`

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   browserButtonEvent();
};
```

There's a catch though. Both the back button and the resfresh button will invoke this function. That's as far as I went when I came across the same issue.

Comment: You probably mean `onbeforeunload`... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload

Comment: No I don't mean onbeforeunload, since this method also gets called when I refresh the page by clicking F5 as an example. I only want to find out whether it is the back button, or the foward button that has been pressed

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, but would probably need an alteration in your whole website/application:
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/